# Keyboard shortcut to open paste menu in Word

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

After pasting text in MS Word 2007, there is a little paste menu that you can click to change how the text was pasted.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to open that menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. I can tell you I was very happy when I found this one hidden away in the Help --- it's *so* much nicer to be able to access those popup menus with the keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

On MS Word 2010 it is just "Ctrl". Try this.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2007.  Woulda been sweet, though!

Answer (score 0):

The `Edit / Paste Special` option does the same task, although you use it slightly differently (you specify the format first, and then it does the paste). I'm pretty sure that has a keyboard shortcut, or can be assigned one.